# Docusign & Salesforce Quote Templates

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I'm working on a Custom Salesforce Button that will generate a quote in Salesforce and upload into Docusign.

Where I'm getting stuck is I'd like to populate the signature area automatically but can't find a solution.

Since the quote is in PDF form - I don't think Anchor Tags could be a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: are your doing custom API soln or DocuSign DfS solution which will provide many features out-of-the-box? Also are you creating this PDF Form and is it a fillable PDF Form (aka AcroForm)?

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm working with Docusign DfS.  The Quote PDF pulls information from the SF Opportunity Record and converts to a PDF.  I've tried adding a "\s1\" field within the quote record but doesn't populate the signature area automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add anchor tags to your template content in Salesforce CPQ.
Open your template content record.

Place your anchor tags in the location where you want the related eSignature field to appear.
Use the template content’s source editor to make your anchor tags match the background color of your quote document.

In your DocuSign profile, create a DocuSign template and add DocuSign tags.
From the DocuSign app, select Templates on your DocuSign home page, and then select New.
Select Create Template.

Give your template a name and description.
Provide the names of your recipients.

We recommend three primary signature roles: Sender, Signer, and Owner. DocuSign requires that you list the Signer, or multiple Signers, before any other role entry.
Provide a message in the Message to all Recipients field.

From the Standard Fields sidebar, drag the DocuSign tags over the related anchor on your template.

Associate each DocuSign tag with your template’s anchor.
Select your DocuSign tag.

From the Signature sidebar, go to the Location list and view the AutoPlace section. Confirm that the DocuSign tag matches the anchor text that you placed it over.
If you need to change the anchor text associated with this tag, click Edit.
Click Save and Close.

In the DocuSign app, from the Templates section, select your template, and then click i. Copy your ID from the Details box.
In Salesforce CPQ, go to your quote template, and then paste the ID into the DocuSign Template ID fields.